# Replace dot with a space and reverse using java swing

Tags: java, swing, awt

I want to display the dot instead of space whenever click on the View-spaces checkbox MenuItem.My problem is when I click the checkbox it is replacing space with dot but,After when I add some extra text to textarea and click on Viewspace JCheckBox menuitem,it had taken the previous text only and replaced.I have Tried this,Please run my code You can easily understand the problem.Please give some suggestions.....Thank you.
Here is my code:

```
public class VisibleSpaces extends javax.swing.JFrame {
int i=0;
JTextArea tx,lnNum;
JScrollPane scrollpane;
public VisibleSpaces() {
    initComponents();
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    tp = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
    jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    Create = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
    ViewSpace = new javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jMenu1.setText("File");

    Create.setText("Create");
    Create.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            CreateActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(Create);

    ViewSpace.setSelected(true);
    ViewSpace.setText("ViewSpaces");
    ViewSpace.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            ViewSpaceActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jMenu1.add(ViewSpace);

    jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

    setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(tp, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 279, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void ViewSpaceActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
   ViewSpace.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
           String str=tx.getText();
           String previous=str;

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
            if(ViewSpace.getState()){
                tx.setText(previous.replace(" ","."));
        }
            else
                tx.setText(str);
        }
    });
}                                         

private void CreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    final JInternalFrame internalFrame = new JInternalFrame("");
    i++;
    internalFrame.setName("Document"+i);
    internalFrame.setClosable(true);
    internalFrame.setAutoscrolls(true);
    tx=new JTextArea();
    tx.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Miriam Fixed", 0, 13));
    scrollpane=new JScrollPane(tx);
    internalFrame.add(scrollpane);
    tp.add(internalFrame);
    internalFrame.setSize(internalFrame.getMaximumSize());
    internalFrame.pack();
    internalFrame.setVisible(true);
}                                      

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisibleSpaces.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisibleSpaces.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisibleSpaces.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(VisibleSpaces.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new VisibleSpaces().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JMenuItem Create;
private javax.swing.JCheckBoxMenuItem ViewSpace;
private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
private javax.swing.JTabbedPane tp;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Comment: Would be great to read about java naming conventions and code styles first.

Comment: [tl;dr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Too_long;_didn't_read). Learn how to post [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: PLAF changes, menu bars, internal frames.. These all seem to have nothing to do with the problem, so strip them out.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).  Or pretty much what @ImmerAllein commented.. ;)

Comment: I ran your code, But its working fine. First I have entered one "space" and clicked on the View-spaces checkbox MenuItem it is changing into a "dot". Then I entered a "Space" with some extra text (like  this " abc") and clicked on the View-spaces checkbox MenuItem , and it is populating as per your requirement. (Like this ".abc")

Comment: Thank you for reply. No,it was not work.for example write (abc  ) and click on Viewspace checkbox menuitem it was display (abc..) then unchecked and add(def  )and again check checkbox menuitem the result is (abc..)only not (abc..def..)this is the problem with my code.

Comment: *"I know the java conventions and code styles."*  Knowing them and using them are two different things.  We want you to **use them.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not proper, its full with bad practice. After a lot of effort I understood your problem. I am just giving the solution of the specific problem, but try to follow the comments given to your question for better understanding of the uses of Java swing components.

Solution:

change this portion of your code

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
            if(ViewSpace.getState()){
                tx.setText(previous.replace(" ","."));
        }
            else
                tx.setText(str);
        }
```

with this one

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                if(ViewSpace.getState()){
                    tx.setText(tx.getText().replace(" ","."));

            }
                else
                {
                    String last = tx.getText().substring(tx.getText().length()-1, tx.getText().length());
                    String rest = tx.getText().substring(0, tx.getText().length()-1);
                    if(!last.equals("."))
                    tx.setText(tx.getText().replace("."," "));
                    else
                        {
                        rest=rest.replace("."," ");
                        tx.setText(rest+".");

                        }
                }
```

Comment: had you run my code? My problem is not this.First run my program,goto file menu then click on create then write text with spaces(abc  ) then click on viewspaces and agaign click on viewspace (output will be abc..)then click on viewspace(output will be abc  )then add some text (ex abc  def  )then click on viewspace(output will be abc..) but expected output is (abc..def..).this was the problem not above you had mentioned.

Comment: @user3675761 Yes. change the code as I suggested. It will do exactly same you want.

Comment: k,but when I write text like(abc.)ie end of statement.That is also replaced with space.This is the problem with above code.

Comment: @user3675761 edited my answer. Try with this code.